# how to display the names in a jsp page according to name

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets

i have a page editpatient.jsp which includes a page patientlist.jsp. when you run editpatient.jsp then it displays all the records present in the database.I have a dropdown and also a search field to specify searches. So when i run editpatient.jsp then it displays all the records in the manner it is stored in DB. So i wanted to sort it according to name and display.So please tell me how to do the same. when you hit the name or email or city then it will sort accordingly

patientlist.jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="DB.*" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.evenRow{
                height: 50px;
                background-color: white;
                text-transform: none;
                text-shadow: none;
                color: black;
        }

        .evenRow:hover 
        {
            background-color: #C2FEF0;
        }

            .row{
                height: 50px;
                background-color: #E4E6E6;
                text-transform: none;
                text-shadow: none;
                color: black;
                }

            .row:hover {
            background-color: #C2FEF0;
            }
</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>

<table style="border-collapse: collapse;overflow-x: scroll; width:97%">
                            <tr style="background-color:grey;height:50px"> 
                                <th style="min-width: 100px">
                                    NAME    
                                </th>
                                <th style="min-width: 100px">
                                    CITY    
                                </th>
                                <th style="min-width: 100px">
                                    LAST VISIT  
                                </th>
                                <th style="min-width: 100px">
                                    MOBILE  
                                </th>
                                <th style="min-width: 100px">
                                    EMAIL   
                                </th>
                                <th style="min-width: 100px">
                                    STATUS  
                                </th>
                                <th style="min-width: 100px">
                                    VIEW    
                                </th>
                                <th style="min-width: 100px">
                                    EDIT    
                                </th>
                            </tr>
            <%
                DataBaseConnection db = new DataBaseConnection();
                Connection con = db.connet();
                PreparedStatement pt = con
                        .prepareStatement("select * from Patient");
                ResultSet rs = pt.executeQuery();

                String searchBy = request.getParameter("searchBy");
                String searchElement = request.getParameter("searchElement");

                int count = 0;
                int index = -1;
                boolean name = false;
                if ("city".equalsIgnoreCase(searchBy))
                    index = 9;//change the index to the index of the city
                else if ("firstName".equalsIgnoreCase(searchBy))
                    index = 1;
                else if ("lastName".equalsIgnoreCase(searchBy))
                    index = 2;
                else if ("name".equalsIgnoreCase(searchBy)) {
                    index = 1;
                    name = true;
                }

                while (rs.next()) {
                    if (searchElement == null
                            || ((searchElement.equals(rs.getString(index)) && !name) || (name && searchElement
                                    .equalsIgnoreCase(rs.getString(index) + " "
                                            + rs.getString(index + 1))))) {

                    if (count++ % 2 == 0) {
            %>

                                <tr class="evenRow" >
                                    <td>
                                        <%=rs.getString(1)%>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <%=rs.getString(2)%>                                        
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <%=rs.getString(3)%>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <%=rs.getString(4)%>                                        
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <%=rs.getString(5)%>                                        
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <%=rs.getString(6)%>                                        
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
<form action="getPatientDetails.jsp"><input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="<%=count%>"/><input type="submit" value="view"></form>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a onclick="renderEdit(<%out.println("edit");%>)"><%
                                            out.println("edit");
                                        %></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>   
                <%
                        } else {
                    %>
                                <tr class="row">
                                    <td>
                                                                                <%=rs.getString(1)%>

                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                                                                <%=rs.getString(2)%>

                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                                                                <%=rs.getString(3)%>

                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                                                                <%=rs.getString(4)%>

                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                                                                <%=rs.getString(5)%>

                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                                                                <%=rs.getString(6)%>

                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a onclick="renderView(<%out.println("view");%>)"><%
                                            out.println("view");
                                        %></a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a onclick="renderEdit(<%out.println("edit");%>)"><%
                                            out.println("edit");
                                        %></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            <%
                                }
                    }
                }
                            %>
                        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

editpatient.jsp

```
    <%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html 
         PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html>
        <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script>
    $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
var request;

function getRequestObject()
{
    if (window.ActiveXObject) 
    {
        return(new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"));
    } 
    else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
    {
        return(new XMLHttpRequest());
    }
    else {
        return(null);
    }
}

function sendRequest() 
{
    request = getRequestObject();
    request.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
    var address =  "patientList.jsp?searchBy=" + document.getElementById("searchBy").value + "&searchElement="+ document.getElementById("searchElement").value;
    request.open("GET", address, true);
    request.send(null);
}

function handleResponse() 
{
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)
    {
        document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = request.responseText;
    }
}
</script>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Edit Patient</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="f1" name="f1" method="post" onsubmit="ccheck();" >
        <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
          });
        </script>
        <section id="page" > <!-- Defining the #page section with the section tag -->
            <header > <!-- Defining the header section of the page with the appropriate tag -->
                    <hgroup align="center">
                        <h3>Edit Patient</h3>
                    </hgroup>
            </header>
            <section id="articles"> <!-- A new section with the articles -->
                <!-- Article 1 start -->
                <div class="line"></div>  <!-- Dividing line -->
                <article id="article1"> <!-- The new article tag. The id is supplied so it can be scrolled into view. -->
                    <div class="articleBody clear">
                        search:
                        <select id="searchBy">
                            <option value="lastName">Last Name</option>
                            <option value="firstName">First Name</option>
                            <option value="name">Name</option>
                            <option value="city">City</option>
                        </select>
                        <input id="searchElement"/> 
                        <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="sendRequest();"/>
                    </div>
                </article>
                        <div id="table" align="center">
                            <jsp:include page="patientList.jsp" />
                        </div>
                </article>
            </section>
            <footer> <!-- Marking the footer section -->
               <div class="line"></div>
               <a href="#" class="up">Go UP</a>
            </footer>   
        </section> <!-- Closing the #page section -->
            <!-- JavaScript Includes -->
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2/jquery.scrollTo-min.js"></script>
            <script src="script.js"></script>
      </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this links help you.

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/10/03/33-javascript-solutions-for-sorting-tables/

http://www.allmyscripts.com/Table_Sort/

Also let us know if you tried anything already

Comment: i have already done that still thanks for posting the answer.So i am upvoting it.

Answer (score 0):

ASFAIK, The solution to your problem is ,you can use the jquery in jsp code, So you can find all Library's and include in it  . There is no need to worry about sort and editing . Jquery has the `Data Tables` which has inbuilt  API to sort the data in listed tables, its possible to edit the data in the table. 
[Reference Edit](http://www.datatables.net/blog/Inline_editing)   [Reference Sort](http://datatables.net/api#fnSort)  [How to use data table in jsp pages](http://fabianosoriani.wordpress.com/2011/05/06/adding-dynamic-ajax-data-to-datatable-a-jquery-table-plugin/)

Comment: thanks for answering but the link you gave is using php and in my project i am not using php

Comment: Okies.. I have given only it as reference,the extend your search on data tables using javascript

Answer (score 0):

1.First store the dropdown /search value in Model class(using setter).
2.When you fired a query to fetch the details from database append the dropdown /search value which is stored in model class(using getter).
3.After fetch the value from DB render the dataTable .
 Suggestion :
Please Follow the any one MVC architecture (Like Spring MVC architecture) to avoid the complexity of the your project.
Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly answers to question.
Try grid like [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) which takes care of things like `sorting`, `searching`, etc..